# How to Solve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for clearCache() method on Junit for spring + mule ESB project

Tags: java, spring, junit, mule, mule-studio

I have to make the unit tests for a Mule ESB + Spring project and It was going well until I found the following stopper: 
I got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.clearCache()V 
when I execute the test:

**I only call the unit test as follow:**

```
//annotations
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/platform-context-test.xml" } )
public class AbstractExceptionUnitTest {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AbstractExceptionUnitTest.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Testing " + AbstractExceptionUnitTest.class);
        JndiSetup.doSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Method testApp.
     */
    @Test
    public void test() {
        LOG.info("Testing!!");
    }
}
```

**I saw as output of spring context :**

INFO  17-10 20:09:33,155 - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class com.tesing.AbstractExceptionUnitTest ]: using defaults.
INFO  17-10 20:09:33,181 - Testing class com.tesing.AbstractExceptionUnitTest
INFO  17-10 20:09:33,248 - Data Source MySQL --> myDataSourceDS bonded.
INFO  17-10 20:09:33,356 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [platform-context-test.xml]
INFO  17-10 20:09:33,689 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@7af485b: startup date [Thu Oct 17 20:09:33 COT 2013]; root of context hierarchy

**and after that the test shows the error:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.clearCache()V
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:325)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

And here the part of relevant dependencies of the project:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
      <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.0-stable</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
      <artifactId>kettle-db</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.0-stable</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
      <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.0-stable</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>directory-naming</groupId>
      <artifactId>naming-java</artifactId>
      <version>0.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central-mule.repository</id>
      <name>Mule Plugins</name>
      <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>PentahoRepo</id>
      <name>Pentaho repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>mulesoft-release</id>
      <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
```

**Please any ideas to try solve this NoShuchMethodError ??**

Comment: I resolved some similar NoSuchMethod upgrading the version of the spring dependencies or excluding in the dependency that do reference to an old spring dependency but in this project I not found spring-core dependencies older than 3.1.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

Try the TestExecutionListeners anotation.

```
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/platform-context-test.xml" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading all possible spring dependencies to 3.4.0 spring version.